# A-Frame Samsung gearVR example

Tags: aframe, webvr

i am trying to create an example with A-frame using my samsung gear VR. Can you please give me an example of how to track clicks,touch etc

Comment: to be specific, i want to track the input from my gearVR device to map it to the clicks of aframe entities. Eg: touch, swipe etc

Comment: Please share your research and what libraries you intend to use

Comment: Hi SriKanth - this should help you get started https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/components/gearvr-controls.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have GearVR with Controller, I found [laser-controls](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/components/laser-controls.html) useful:

```
<a-entity laser-controls raycaster="showLine:true;" line="color:#eee; opacity:0.33;"></a-entity>
```

Comment: Ok. I will check it out.